# How to send Ctrl-C to a script running in a tmux window, instead of the window itself?

Tags: tmux

I want to be able to use Ctrl-C in a tmux window to close a running script.

I am starting a process on system boot, which i want to keep running in tmux. 
My command to do so is:

```
tmux new -d -s 'my-session' -n my-window '/opt/script.sh'
```

This script does a couple of things, and then runs `python3 script.py`, which will keep running. 
I want to be able to attach to this tmux window, and then use Ctrl-C to end the python command, without closing the tmux window.  
Instead, when I do that it immediately closes the tmux window. 
Is there a way to send Ctrl-C to either the python or shell script (either one should work to end the script) ?

My tmux version is `tmux 3.2a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```bash
# create the session/window and an interactive shell will be
# running in the window
tmux new -d -s my-session -n my-window
# send the command to the interactive shell
tmux send -t my-session:my-window '/opt/script.sh' Enter
```